# Correct permissions for user repl in Postgres14

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to setup streaming replication.
On my master I've [removed connect priviliges](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-security-things-to-avoid-in-real-life/) for public:

```
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM public;
```

For User repl I've tried to allow access everywhere again

```
GRANT pg_read_all_data TO repl;
GRANT pg_write_all_data TO repl;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public FROM public to repl;
```

Users currently look like this

```
postgres=# \du;
                                                 List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         |              Member of               
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------
 pgpool    |                                                            | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 repl      | Replication                                                | {pg_read_all_data,pg_write_all_data}
```

Now on my slave a connection test fails with:

```
psql -h db-master-p 5432  -U repl -d template1 
psql: error: connection to server at "db-master", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  permission denied for database "template1" 
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
```

Which permissions are needed for User *repl* and how to correctly apply them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up schemas and databases, and the `CREATE` and `CONNECT` privileges.

A user for streaming replication does *not* not privileges on any database objects like schemas and tables, since it only consumes WAL. The user only needs to have the `REPLICATION` property.

There are two types of connections in PostgreSQL: normal client-server connections and replication connections. Your test with `psql` tests the former, which requires the `CONNECT` privilege on the database.

To establish a replication connection with `psql`, user the `replication` connection string property:

```bash
psql 'host=db-master port=5432 user=repl replication=on'
```

You cannot specify a database with a replication connection.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz! So in other words all is correct so far and I can remove `pg_read_all_data,pg_write_all_data` from user repl again. May I ask one more question. In pg_hba.conf should I just trust the user `repl` or is it best practise to use a password for replication?

Comment: If the standby is safe, you can trust it. If you don't trust all users on the standby machine, use a password or certificate authentication.

Comment: Great, this should do it to find my way. Regarding your first answer. The strange thing is that most howto on replication check the connection of user repl as shown above. f.e. https://girders.org/postgresql/2021/11/05/setup-postgresql14-replication/ but what you write with WAL files reading only makes sense!

Comment: I'd always trust the PostgreSQL documentation over any HOWTO.

Comment: Agree! Just tried your suggestion and replication works nicely. Yeah the elephant is runng. thanks Laurenz!